# Install matlab as sudo doesnt start the gui

Tags: software-installation, 17.10, matlab

So basically I'm trying to install the newest matlab. I navigate to the matlab download folder and write "sudo ./install", but nothing opens up, it just says:
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
Finished

And after that nothing happens. And when I try without sudo it will open the install gui but I can (of course) not install because I don't have root permission. I have also tried simulating log in as root by "sudo -i" but it gives exact same result as just using "sudo ./install".

Im using 17.10 with Gnome desktop installed on a HP envy 13" laptop (AD004no).

Comment: Try again in a Xorg session instead of the default Wayland. Does it work as expected?

Comment: @MichaelBay yes that did the trick! Thank you very much!